# Should third parties edit Answers when Question requirements change in simple ways?

Tags: discussion

If the rules of a challenge change in a simple way, such as a different constant, and the required change to all existing answers is simply changing that constant, can/should the question author or other third parties submit edits for the answers?

Comment: While not an answer to this specific question, [this is relevant](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1347/14215).

Comment: Changing a constant might sound like a simple change but may invalidate answers/approaches (e.g. runtime becomes unrealistic).

Comment: @Howard sure, but the rule change is a given in this question. Once the rule is changed, what should happen to the answer that is now invalid?

Comment: Then I'd say you are not allowed to change the question, see link in @Geobits comment.

Comment: I think that the most polite way to handle this would be to post a comment asking the answer author to update their answer and downvote the question.